# Grouping sub-arrays with nonidentical items

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6

I have a 2D array like

```
[ [ 'B', 'O', 'C' ],
  [ 'J', 'B', 'F' ],
  [ 'F', 'B', 'D' ],
  [ 'F', 'D', 'W' ],
  [ 'N', 'F', 'X' ],
  [ 'X', 'J', 'F' ],
  [ 'T', 'Y', 'H' ],
  [ 'R', 'Q', 'P' ] ],
```

And i need to group the sub-arrays such that in the resulting 3D array each group should contain only the sub-arrays with items non identical with each other's items. Besides there shouldn't be any duplicate groups such as listing the same sub-arrays in a different order.

For the given array the result is;

```
[ [ [ 'B', 'O', 'C' ],
    [ 'F', 'D', 'W' ],
    [ 'T', 'Y', 'H' ],
    [ 'R', 'Q', 'P' ] ],
  [ [ 'J', 'B', 'F' ],
    [ 'T', 'Y', 'H' ],
    [ 'R', 'Q', 'P' ] ],
  [ [ 'F', 'B', 'D' ],
    [ 'T', 'Y', 'H' ],
    [ 'R', 'Q', 'P' ] ],
  [ [ 'N', 'F', 'X' ],
    [ 'T', 'Y', 'H' ],
    [ 'R', 'Q', 'P' ],
    [ 'B', 'O', 'C' ] ],
  [ [ 'X', 'J', 'F' ],
    [ 'T', 'Y', 'H' ],
    [ 'R', 'Q', 'P' ],
    [ 'B', 'O', 'C' ] ] ]
```

My code works fine but something back in my mind says i am doing some overkill and it can be done better. Any ideas how this job might be done any better?

```js
var arr = [ [ 'B', 'O', 'C' ],
            [ 'J', 'B', 'F' ],
            [ 'F', 'B', 'D' ],
            [ 'F', 'D', 'W' ],
            [ 'N', 'F', 'X' ],
            [ 'X', 'J', 'F' ],
            [ 'T', 'Y', 'H' ],
            [ 'R', 'Q', 'P' ] ],
 result = arr.reduce((s,t,i,a) => t.used ? s
                                         : (s.push(a.map((_,j) => a[(i+j)%a.length])
                                                    .reduce((p,c,k) => k-1 ? p.every(t => t.every(n => c.every(v => n !== v))) ? (c.used = true, p.push(c),p) : p
                                                                           : [p].every(t => t.every(n => c.every(v => n !== v))) ? (c.used = true, [p,c]) : [p])),s),[]);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2))
```

The code is slightly complicated but in the heart of it lies;

```
.reduce((p,c,k) => k-1 ? p.every(t => t.every(n => c.every(v => n !== v))) ? (c.used = true, p.push(c),p) : p
                                                                           : [p].every(t => t.every(n => c.every(v => n !== v))) ? (c.used = true, [p,c]) : [p]))
```

which will take

```
[ [ 'B', 'O', 'C' ],
  [ 'J', 'B', 'F' ],
  [ 'F', 'B', 'D' ],
  [ 'F', 'D', 'W' ],
  [ 'N', 'F', 'X' ],
  [ 'X', 'J', 'F' ],
  [ 'T', 'Y', 'H' ],
  [ 'R', 'Q', 'P' ] ],
```

and turn it into

```
[ [ 'B', 'O', 'C' ],
  [ 'F', 'D', 'W' ],
  [ 'T', 'Y', 'H' ],
  [ 'R', 'Q', 'P' ] ]
```

and will mark all sub arrays as used. Then we will rotate the given array  with `a.map((_,j) => a[(i+j)%a.length])`, up until an unused sub array is at index 0 position and repeat the same job.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but what conceptually are you trying to do?  Because at a glance, I'd think that the solution you get depends on the order of the elements of the outer array, which seems strange.  That is, I start with item 1 ` (say `['B', 'O', 'C']`), now I add another item which has no elements in common with item 1.  there could be many such choices.  but after adding that item, the next item will have 6 restrictions instead of 3, and *which* six depends on my choice of item 2.  so your final result depends on both the order of the items and your iteration method.

Comment: @jonah OK i got your point; however whichever second sub-array, with no common elements with the sub array #1, you chose to add won't change the result. Think of it like this. Each sub-array designate a triangle and i want the disconnected ones in a group.

Comment: Consider: `[[1,2], [3,4], [3,5], [5,6]`.  If after `[1,2]` I choose `[3,4]` then I can also choose `[5,6]`.  If after `[1,2]` I choose `[3,5]` then I'm done.

Comment: @jonah In your test case there are multiple sets of disconnected edges and as you have figured out `[[1,2], [3,4], [3,5], [5,6]]` would return `[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[1,2],[3,5]]]

Comment: ah, ok i see what you want now

Answer (score 1):

Cascaded ternaries, generic variable names, obfuscated logic produces write-only and mind-boggling code that requires deciphering for anyone, including you in the future.

Let's try to write a self-explanatory code:

```
function groupUnique(input) {
    let results = [];
    for (let inputRow of input) {
        let collectedCells = new Set(inputRow);
        let draft = [inputRow].concat(
            input.filter(row => {
                if (row.some(cell => collectedCells.has(cell)))
                    return false;
                for (let cell of row)
                    collectedCells.add(cell);
                return true;
            })
        );
        let alreadyAdded = results.some(res =>
            res.length == draft.length && res.every(row => draft.includes(row))
        );
        if (!alreadyAdded)
            results.push(draft);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think your code does the job more or less about the same complexity. I know, i tend to use a lot of ternary and bracket operator and single letter variables. But i can perceive them as blocks of code patterns and pretty easily figure out what's going on. OK tomorrow i will test your code to see how it will perform. + for your time and efforts.